# What to do when there is no ground cable?

Tags: ground, grounding, wiring, heat, wire

I'm trying to connect a heating cable (heating tape) which is constant wattage type. This cable requires 240V. However, I realized there is no ground cable as you can see in the picture below. it only has two identical bus wires that will be heated up. I am going to connect a neutral wire to one of the bus wires and live cable to another bus wire (using temperature controller and SSR).

Is there any way I can ground (earth) this cable? Also, one question is, what is the purpose of the wire that is covering the yellow cable? Is it only for the protection?

[image]

Comment: @Mike Please note that while removing "Thank you" is considered a substantial edit due to character count, it's not a good idea to remove that line while leaving all the typos in there. The next person willing to fix those typos will then struggle with the character count.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the braid/ shield as a protective earth similar to a neutral screen cable, it should act as a path for fault current if ever the cables being covered become damaged.

Answer (score 1):

It has the ground connection, it is the shield. The purpose of this shield is not any different from metal case of solid heater.

You may also use a ground fault interrupter, similar to this:

[image]